# I am using fork and pipe.Child process is not getting killed when parent process is aborted abruptly(ex.segmentation fault)

Tags: c

I'am using fork to create child and parent processes and used pipe to send and receive messages between them.I'm running parent process with some inputs and it calls child process.If parent process is executed successfully, child process is getting killed automatically but If i press ctrl+c when parent process is running or if there is any segmentation fault, parent process is getting killed but child process is not getting killed.

Can anybody post me the logic to kill child process when parent process is abrupted ?

Comment: If the program crashes it's not much you can do really, except fixing the bug. For catching CTRL-C check out the [`signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) function and the `SIGINT` signal.

Comment: For ctrl+c , i can catch the signal but if parent process dies due to segmentation fault?

Comment: For crashes, the only solution is to fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use a pipe for communication, this should be easy.

Pipe reads block until there's data to read and if parent process is the writer and died, you get `EOF` immediately. If your parent process never closes it's write end, then you have a reliable way to detect death.

Pipe writes hit `SIGPIPE` and return `EPIPE` from the call if the signal is ignored when there are no readers.

In the child, select (if you can block) on the fd of pipe and kill the process at appropriate time. There is no `SIGCHLD` equivalent to parent dying.

`man 7 pipe` for a good overview. Excerpt:

```
If  all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from
the pipe will see end-of-file (read(2) will return 0).  If all file descriptors referring to the read end of  a
pipe have been closed, then a write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process.  If
the calling process is ignoring this signal, then write(2) fails with the error  EPIPE.   An  application  that
uses  pipe(2)  and  fork(2) should use suitable close(2) calls to close unnecessary duplicate file descriptors;
this ensures that end-of-file and SIGPIPE/EPIPE are delivered when appropriate.
```